# Putting JSON answer in a variable with Swift

Tags: json, swift

I try to put the answer I get from an JSON API to a variable.
But it doesn't work. It says `info` was never used. I can print decoded.Data.name in the console. But I cannot put it in a variable. What am I doing wrong?

I need to use this variable outside of this function. I tried to use var info with a placeholder outside of this function so it cannot say it is not used. But it didn't work.

I get the error:

Initialization of variable 'info' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it.

```
func parseJSON(weatherData: Data) {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    do{
        let decodedData =  try decoder.decode(WeatherData.self, from: weatherData)
        print(decodedData.name)
        
        var info = decodedData.name
        
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: *But i cannot put it in a variable*. You do put it in a variable but you don't use it. If you want to use the data outside of the function you have to declare `info` *outside of the function*.

Comment: Thank you for your very fast answer. Somewhere else in the code i use tore.text = info to change the text of a label. But it doesnt accept my variable. It says Use of unresolved identifier 'info'.

Comment: You have to declare `var info = ""` on the highest scope/level as necessary and assign  `info = decodedData.name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ca return data from this function and can use that outside this function like this

```
 func parseJSON(weatherData: Data)-> WeatherData? {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do{
            let decodedData =  try decoder.decode(WeatherData.self, from: weatherData)
            print(decodedData.name)
            
            return decodedData
            
        } catch {
              print(error)
            return nil
          
        }
    }
```

Then use it like this

```
    if let info = parseJSON(weatherData: yourData) {
            print(info.name)

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I already solved with the method of the other user. :)

Comment: Upvoting is disabled for me because im new sorry

Comment: I did now :) :) :)